# Enumerate every record in SQL with @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query in MySQL

```
SELECT 
@rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum,
notifications_posts.from_user AS source,
notifications_posts.on_post_id AS destination,
notifications_posts.in_group_id,
groups.group_name AS group_name,
notifications_posts.on_post_id AS other_record_id,
user_info.first_name,
user_info.last_name,
user_info.user_id,
notifications_posts.date,
posts.title AS 'title',
user_rights.right AS 'right',
'article' AS notification_type
FROM notifications_posts
INNER
    JOIN user_info
    ON notifications_posts.from_user = user_info.user_id
INNER
    JOIN posts
    ON posts.id = notifications_posts.on_post_id
INNER
    JOIN groups
    ON groups.group_id = notifications_posts.in_group_id
INNER
    JOIN user_rights
    ON user_rights.group_id = notifications_posts.in_group_id AND user_rights.user_id = user_info.user_id
```

and i get

[image]

Why i get `NULL` at `rownum`?

And second of all, i need to group records by that id

```
GROUP BY rownum;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's much preferable to just order the results (in MySQL) and then add the row numbers in your application. If you insist though:

**Warning:** any query that uses variables this way, may be broken in a future version of MySQL.

```
SELECT 
    @rownum := @rownum+1 AS rownum,
    notifications_posts.from_user AS source,
    notifications_posts.on_post_id AS destination,
    notifications_posts.in_group_id,
    groups.group_name AS group_name,
    notifications_posts.on_post_id AS other_record_id,
    user_info.first_name,
    user_info.last_name,
    user_info.user_id,
    notifications_posts.date,
    posts.title AS 'title',
    user_rights.right AS 'right',
    'article' AS notification_type
FROM 
    (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS dummy                  -- initial value
CROSS 
    JOIN notifications_posts
INNER
    JOIN user_info
    ON notifications_posts.from_user = user_info.user_id
INNER
    JOIN posts
    ON posts.id = notifications_posts.on_post_id
INNER
    JOIN groups
    ON groups.group_id = notifications_posts.in_group_id
INNER
    JOIN user_rights
    ON user_rights.group_id = notifications_posts.in_group_id 
    AND user_rights.user_id = user_info.user_id 
ORDER BY                                         -- you need 
    whatever ;                                   -- ORDER BY clause
```

Comment: this works, but will it work on a much bigger query? this is the actually query http://codepad.org/ZCYrlXwh

Comment: Depends what you want the numbers to be. Every row a different row number? Or numbering should restart from 1 for every Union part?

Comment: i have 3 unions, i want them to be 1 2 3 4 5 depending on the date that have been posted, get me?

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize the variable @rownum with the statement (SELECT rownum:=0) r

```
 select  @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum,a.*
     from
     (SELECT 
       notifications_posts.from_user AS source,
       notifications_posts.on_post_id AS destination,
       notifications_posts.in_group_id,
       groups.group_name AS group_name,
       ........
       <remaining query>
       )a,(SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```

**EDIT**: So your full query should be

```
SELECT 
@rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum,a.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
    notifications_posts.from_user AS source,
    notifications_posts.on_post_id AS destination,
    notifications_posts.in_group_id,
    groups.group_name AS group_name,
    notifications_posts.on_post_id AS other_record_id,
    user_info.first_name,
    user_info.last_name,
    user_info.user_id,
    notifications_posts.date,
    posts.title AS 'title',
    user_rights.right AS 'right',
    'article' AS notification_type
    FROM notifications_posts
    INNER
        JOIN user_info
        ON notifications_posts.from_user = user_info.user_id
    INNER
        JOIN posts
        ON posts.id = notifications_posts.on_post_id
    INNER
        JOIN groups
        ON groups.group_id = notifications_posts.in_group_id
    INNER
        JOIN user_rights
        ON user_rights.group_id = notifications_posts.in_group_id AND user_rights.user_id = user_info.user_id
)a, (SELECT @rownum:=0 )r
```

Comment: You again? Thank you, but i already did that `(SELECT rownum:=0) r` thing and got `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':=0) r INNER JOIN user_info ON notifications_posts.from_user = user_inf' at line 15`

Comment: Try (Select @rownum:=0) instead

Comment: http://codepad.org/HQr0D4FR gives me `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias` , did i wrote something wrong?

Comment: if i used `(SELECT @rownum:=0) r` instead `(SELECT @rownum:=0 r)` , did i solve it?

Comment: you should use.. (SELECT @rownum:=0) r

Comment: AnandPhadke posted same exemple with `SELECT @rownum:=0;` at the begining, and i have to fix the entire query, that's only a part of it http://codepad.org/ZCYrlXwh

Answer (score 0):

1. Set rownum to 0 before you run your query.
2. Grouping by rownum won't make any difference - the rownum would be different for every row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @rownum:=0;
SELECT 
@rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum,
notifications_posts.from_user AS source,
notifications_posts.on_post_id AS destination,
notifications_posts.in_group_id,
groups.group_name AS group_name,
notifications_posts.on_post_id AS other_record_id,
user_info.first_name,
user_info.last_name,
user_info.user_id,
notifications_posts.date,
posts.title AS 'title',
user_rights.right AS 'right',
'article' AS notification_type
FROM notifications_posts
INNER
    JOIN user_info
    ON notifications_posts.from_user = user_info.user_id
INNER
    JOIN posts
    ON posts.id = notifications_posts.on_post_id
INNER
    JOIN groups
    ON groups.group_id = notifications_posts.in_group_id
INNER
    JOIN user_rights
    ON user_rights.group_id = notifications_posts.in_group_id AND user_rights.user_id = user_info.user_id;
```

Comment: what is this `user_info.user_id(@rownum:=0)` ??? have anything to do with `user_info.user_id` ?

Comment: Updated the query pls try now

Comment: for exanmple this http://codepad.org/VOuGIOtc outputs `@rownum:=0
0
` executes only the first select